# Retrieve HttpRequestMessage.RequestUri from Microsoft.AspNet.Http.HttpRequest

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm porting ASP.NET MVC app to ASP.NET Core 3.1.
In old app we use API Controllers which operate a lot with HttpRequestMessage.RequestUri.
I am looking for some way how I can rebuild that RequestUri in Core app.
Not sure that using UriBuilder and reconstruct RequestUri from HttpRequest chunks is a good idea.

Is there any way to do it correctly ?

**EDIT 1**
The Problem:
RequestUri was supply by asp.net mvc,  so we use as it was built. Now asp.net core supply HttpRequest which has that info spitted across set of chunks. To keep app running  without huge refactoring, I need to build RequestUri from HttpRequest in the same manner how it was done by asp.net mvc.

However I need cover bunch of cases:

- http/https
- Ports
- different env - local/develop/test/production
- encoding/decoding
- leading/trailing '/' char
- different Url formats with domain support
- support IE/Chrome/mobile
- trimming any spaces

maybe smth else, this is just initial list from top of my head.
That's why I'm looking for some robust and comprehensive solution.

Comment: You can access the `HttpContext` which contains the HTTP-specific information of an HTTP request. `HttpContext.Request` should get you where you want. If you're in a web app, you'll need to reference the docs for how to access it. Here's a link to the API reference for the class. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpcontext?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: @jandrew
Well, I have Request which is now (Microsoft.AspNet.Http.HttpRequest), I need somehow reassemble from it RequestUri value as it was in old MVC

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by reassemble? Is there some specific request information you need?

Comment: @jandrew Edited question

Answer (score 0):

In my ASP.NET Core application, I'm building the Uri from the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext` class using an extension class :

```
public static class HttpContextExtension
{
    public static string Uri(this HttpContext context)
    {
        string uri = $"{context.Request.Scheme}//{context.Request.Host}:{context.Request.Host.Port}{context.Request.Path}";
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request.QueryString.ToString())) uri += $"/{context.Request.QueryString}";
        return uri;
    }
}
```

And I'm using it this way to get the Uri :

```
string uri = context.Uri();
```

Where `context` is a `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext` object.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I am talking about. You combine Uri from Request chunks. However port info is missed here, maybe smth else is missed.
I was thinking smth about GetMyWorkingUrlBackAgain() method and that's it )))

Comment: Maybe it is accessible with context.Request.Host.Port ?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. But still there are few more open questions -  like has leading trailing '/' char, encoding/escaping, http/https, localhost (need loopback for local development), etc

Comment: For the remaining opened questions, please search a bit on the internet, you'll find solutions easily.